# what SQL Statement should i use to display the correct ID from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Search function works well 50% but not all data are fetched correctly. i want to display data from two tables but unfortunately from the second table it shows me always just the first row:

Those data i want to be displayed:
*personname, personsurname, persondepartment, personboard (from tblperson) and startdate and enddate from members.*

This is my query right now and when i search id displays exact data as i want but from the members table it fetches only the first row with start and end date.

```
"select * FROM tblperson, members 
 where personname = '$personname' AND personsurname = '$personsurname'
 GROUP BY personname";
```

and this is my php code:

```
for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
  {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'. Name: ';
     echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['personname']));
    echo '<br />PersonID: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['personid']);
     echo '<td><a href="editpdata.php?personid=' . $row['personid'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
     echo '</strong><br />Surname: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['personsurname']);
     echo '<br />Department: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['persondepartment']);
     echo '<br />Board: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['personboard']);
     echo '<br />Start Date: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['startdate']);
     echo '<br />End Date: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['enddate']);
     echo '</p>';
  }
```

Comment: explicitly set columns for both tables in your select statement, take note your are currently vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: To be honest i am not good in SQL either in PHP. if you can show me an example maybe i will try to implement it. The only problem right now is that every person that i search with name and surname in return i receive wrong ID and wrong Start End Date from the second table 'members' every thing else is correct.

Comment: Any non-aggregated fields in SELECT have to be in GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.personid, p.personname, p.personsurname, p.persondepartment, p.personboard,
  max(m.startdate) AS last_startdate, max(m.enddate) AS last_enddate
FROM tblperson AS p
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON p.personid = m.personid ## please check this line
WHERE p.personname = '?'
AND p.personsurname = '?'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

If you are using MySQL and personid is unique key, you can do:

```
GROUP BY p.personid
```

Comment: Hi guys, I just tried this query and seems that it is working fine. i will try the  other suggestions also.SELECT * 
   FROM tblperson
   JOIN members WHERE personname = '$personname'                    AND personsurname = '$personsurname' AND members.person_id = tblperson.personid GROUP BY tblperson.personid";       Danke @SIDU

Comment: Technically you should group  by all non-aggregated fields in select. Usually personid is primary key, so group by personid will return expected result, but does not mean it is standard SQL